# Classic ASP submitting multi-value checkbox selections and then displaying choices with other table items

Tags: sql, vbscript, asp-classic

I've looked all over the web and cannot find the answer to this riddle.

I am still using VBSCRIPT (Classic ASP) and I have two tables in SQL, (Jobs and Tasks)

**Jobs Table**

ID

TaskID

**Tasks Table**

ID

TaskName

I basically have a form where a new job can be created and the user can choose one or more tasks from the Tasks Table using checkboxes. Let's assume the user checks Task #1 and #3. This form then submits the selected tasks and then inserts it into the TaskID field inside the Jobs table with a value like '1,3'

I then use this code to parse the values (which works great, I might add):

```
values = rsQuery("TaskID")
selections = Split(values, ",")
For i = 0 To UBound(selections)

<option selected value='Response.Write rsQuery.Fields("TaskID")'>Response.Write rsTasks.Fields("TaskName"))
Next
```

This gives me the items selected, but what I really want is this list mixed in with the other tasks (that were not checked) from the tasks table, without duplicating them. Is it  possible that using an array might help? If so, I'm totally lost on how to use one in this scenario.

Any ideas?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm confused. How do you want it to look? Are you trying to change the query you use to retrieve the data, or the vbscript code you use to display the data? Also, why would you have a multi-valued field - TaskID in the Jobs table should have only one value in it - if a user selects two tasks, two records should be inserted, one for each task.

Comment: There is only one field capturing the TaskID in the form. My form provides multiple checkboxes for the tasks associated with the job.  If the user chooses one or more tasks, that value is stored in the field as a comma separated value.  I don't want multiple rows written to the jobs table since there is only one job.  The example above '1,3' works just fine both writing to and pulling from the jobs table.  I want a resulting page of checkboxes with the list of all tasks (from the tasks table) but show the ones that were chosen (stored in the jobs table) as checked. Thank you for responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the tasks in a recordset. Loop through the recordset to display the tasks and check for the ID in the Jobs.TaskID. If the value exists, show it as checked.

e.g.

```
sTaskID = rsQuery("TaskID")  ' this will have value from jobs table, say 1,3

set rsTasks = server.createobject("adodb.recordset")
ssql = "select * from tasks"
rsTasks.open ssql, <your connection>,....

do while not rsTasks.EOF
    if instr("," & sTaskID & ",", "," & rsTasks("ID") & ",") > 0 then
    ' Enclose the strings within commas, otherwise if the tasks selected has 10, then task ID 1 will show up as checked as well because the string 1 will be found within 10
        bChecked = " checked"
    end if

    %>
    <input type="checkbox" value="<%=rsTasks("ID")%>" <%=bChecked%>><%=rsTasks("TaskName")%>
    <%
    rsTasks.moveNext
loop
```

Please note that the comma separated values may be in the form 1,3 or 1, 3 i.e. a space after comma. You'll need to modify the code accordingly to handle that.

Comment: That worked like a charm! I know this was easy for you, but it is usually the simplest solutions that I somehow overlook. Your single line of code made all the difference! -   
    if instr("," & sTaskID & ",", "," & rsTasks("ID") & ",") > 0 then  
THANK YOU!

Comment: OK, you were right about it storing the values with a space. I've tried adjusting the code to include the space, but cannot seem to make it work.  I've also tried to study up on the workings of the instr() call and am a bit lost.  How do I modify the code to handle the value being 1, 3 instead of 1,3?

Comment: I tried
    sTaskID = Replace(sTaskID, " ", "")
but that didn't help.

Comment: Try this...if instr(", " & sTaskID & ", ", ", " & rsTasks("ID") & ", ") > 0 then

Comment: Thanks, but I'm going to need to rethink this. The TaskIDs are numerous, and the instr() doesn't treat a single digit ID the same as say, a four digit ID ie.. 1, 3045 In fact, if the value is 3045, 3046, 3047 then for some reason 3048 and 3049 are also checked.  Maybe I should write the jobID and all the tasks associated with it to another table altogether.