# Classic Multiselect listbox SQL query

Tags: html, sql-server, asp-classic, listbox, sql-server-express

**Solved!**
Solution:
Editing this in below code will make a neat solution.

```
strCriteria = "" & replace(tagname,", ","','") & ""
```

---

**Original question:**

I have a listbox which is populated by the content of a SQL Server Express table column. The HTML form where the listbox is will generate a HTML table report.

I have the experience that the listbox store the multiple selected values as `VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3` and the SQL query needs these as `'VALUE1', 'VALUE2', 'VALUE3'` - with gnyphs. Therefore it will work with only one value selected as the query will say `'VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3'` - gnyphs around the whole. I have tried using replace as you can see in my code below but as this doesn't work I am not sure i am approaching this correctly.

I have done a lot of Googling and found lots of helpfully articles on this though they are for SQL Server 2005 and earlier and some functions are not supported anymore and I believe there might have come some more handy functions I am unaware about.

How do I approach this the best?

```
<table class="reporttable">
<tr>
<%
dim strSQL,x,strCriteria

strCriteria = replace(tagname,", ","', '")

'Open the recordset object executing the SQL statement and return records
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM dbo.notes WHERE tag IN('" & strCriteria & "') AND ((dt < '" & dTo & "') AND (dt > '" & dFrom & "')) ORDER BY dt DESC"


set objRecordSet = objConn.Execute (strSQL)

for each x in objRecordSet.Fields
     response.write("<th>" & ucase(x.name) & "</th>")
next
%>
</tr>
<%do until objRecordSet.EOF%>
<tr>
<%
for each x in objRecordSet.Fields
     if x.name="no" then%>
              <%else%>
         <td><%Response.Write(x.value)%> </td>
     <%end if
next
%>

<%objRecordSet.MoveNext%>
</tr>
<%
loop

objRecordSet.close
set objRecordSet=nothing
objConn.close
set objConn=nothing
%>
</table>
```

And yes, it have to stay somehow Classic ASP as it has to fit into a very dumb and limited browser.

Comment: http://www.brettb.com/aspmultiselectinputboxes.asp

Comment: The code you posted doesn't seem to have anything to do with your question. How are you getting the values from the form? For that matter, where's the form?

Comment: Where do you get `tagname` from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Classic ASP submitting multi-value checkbox selections and then displaying choices with other table items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23278506/classic-asp-submitting-multi-value-checkbox-selections-and-then-displaying-choic)

Comment: @Lankymart Same solution is found there. I that one didn't show up in my search on Google or here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm confused by your question. But I think I might have the answer you're after.

Are you in fact asking how to put the quotes around your mutli-select-box values?

```
strCriteria = "'" & replace(tagname,", ","','") & "'"
```

The extra "'" on each side starts & terminates the quotes. (or gnyphs as you called them)

Comment: I actually didn't really know how to ask as I didn't know what i wanted but your edit in my string solved my problem. Removing the gnyphs on both sides will work as the SQL string will add them itself. Thank you.

Comment: :) Glad to be of assistance.